# PHP&MySQL error SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
if (isset($_GET["idSubtype"]) || isset($_GET["idReference"]) || isset($_GET["dateStart"])) {
    if (isset($_GET['idSubtype']) ? $idSubtype = $_GET['idSubtype'] : $dateSearch = '') {
        $value = "AND subtypecrop.id = " . $idSubtype ."";
    }
    if (isset($_GET['idReference']) ? $idReference = $_GET['idReference'] : $dateSearch = '') {
        $value = "AND reference.id = " . $idReference . " " . $value;
    }
    if (isset($_GET['dateStart']) ? $dateSearch = $_GET['dateStart'] : $dateSearch = '') {
        $value = "AND dealing.date = ' " . $dateSearch . " ' " . $value;
    }
    $query = "SELECT  dealing.id, type.nameType, subtypecrop.nameSubtype, dealing.date, dealing.price, unit.nameUnit, location.nameLocation, province.nameProvince, reference.nameReference, dealing.other, dealing.url
            FROM dealing 
            JOIN unit ON unit.id = dealing.unit_id 
            JOIN subtypecrop ON subtypecrop.id = dealing.subTypeCrop_id 
            JOIN type ON type.id = subtypecrop.type_id 
            JOIN location ON location.id = dealing.location_id 
            JOIN province ON province.id = location.province_id 
            JOIN reference ON reference.id = dealing.reference_id
            WHERE type.id = 1 " . $value . "";
//    echo $query;
} else {
    $query = "SELECT  dealing.id, type.nameType, subtypecrop.nameSubtype, dealing.date, dealing.price, unit.nameUnit, location.nameLocation, province.nameProvince, reference.nameReference, dealing.other, dealing.url
            FROM dealing 
            JOIN unit ON unit.id = dealing.unit_id 
            JOIN subtypecrop ON subtypecrop.id = dealing.subTypeCrop_id 
            JOIN type ON type.id = subtypecrop.type_id 
            JOIN location ON location.id = dealing.location_id 
            JOIN province ON province.id = location.province_id 
            JOIN reference ON reference.id = dealing.reference_id
            WHERE type.id = 1;";
}
```

Comment: Might help if you included the entire text of the error message.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: And what have you tried to get around this error message?

Comment: Error 404 : Description not found.

Comment: NOTE: Edit your question with the answer to this, not in a comment. If you un-comment the ```echo $query```, what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is with:

```
if (isset($_GET['dateStart']) ? $dateSearch = $_GET['dateStart'] : $dateSearch = '') {
    $value = "AND dealing.date = ' " . $dateSearch . " ' " . $value;
}
```

It should be:

```
if (isset($_GET['dateStart']) ? $dateSearch = $_GET['dateStart'] : $dateSearch = '') {
    $value = "AND dealing.date = '" . $dateSearch . "' " . $value;
}
```

But the extra space wouldn't cause a syntax error.

Also, your code is suseptable to SQL Injection. You should be using prepared statements. That will take care of quoting values and prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a space before the AND clause, because you don't have space and when you concatenate you may get an error. I would write it this way:

```
if (isset($_GET["idSubtype"]) || isset($_GET["idReference"]) || isset($_GET["dateStart"])) {
    $value="";
    if (isset($_GET['idSubtype']) ? $idSubtype = $_GET['idSubtype'] : $dateSearch = '') {
        $value = " AND subtypecrop.id = " . $idSubtype;
    }
    if (isset($_GET['idReference']) ? $idReference = $_GET['idReference'] : $dateSearch = '') {
        $value = $value." AND reference.id = " . $idReference ;
    }
    if (isset($_GET['dateStart']) ? $dateSearch = $_GET['dateStart'] : $dateSearch = '') {
        $value = $value." AND dealing.date = '" . $dateSearch ."'" ;
    }
```